# XQuery Keyword Search Issue

Tags: xml, xquery, exist-db, keyword-search

I'm learning XQuery keyword search and display the results in website. And I found that have useful tutorial website step by step to develop a website.

However, I got an error **(Invalid qname text:match-count)** after execute the code. Is it missing define the namespace?

Anyone can help me to fix the issue? Thank you.

Tutorial Website: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/Keyword_Search

[image: Error Screen]

[image: Coding Part]

Comment: Do you use eXist to try those samples? I think the tutorial was written by and for eXist users.

Comment: Yes. I used by eXist-db platform.
So I haven't idea how to solve on it.

Comment: I have added a tag for exist so hopefully someone with inside knowledge shows up to help you.

Comment: Okay! Thanks Martin.

Answer (score 1):

The function flagged by the error message, `text:match-count()`, has been deprecated and removed from eXist, as was the original eXist-specific full text search operator `&=`. As a result, the article (which the history page reminds me I contributed 10 years and 3 months ago!) is in dire need of an update. These "legacy" full text features were removed from eXist because a far superior solution was added, a Lucene-based full text index, which you can read about in https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/lucene.

The updated article would focus on the new Lucene-based full text index. First, create a collection configuration file, called `collection.xconf`:

```
<collection xmlns="http://exist-db.org/collection-config/1.0">
    <index xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <lucene>
            <text qname="body"/>
            <text qname="biography"/>
        </lucene>
    </index>
</collection>
```

Save this document in the `/db/test` collection. eXide will save you a few steps by offering to (1) store a copy of the document where it really needs to be (in the `/db/system/config/db/test` collection) and (2) reindex the `/db/test` collection to apply the new collection configuration (which you could do manually with `xmldb:reindex("/db/test")`):

With the collection configuration file saved as `/db/system/config/db/test/collection.xconf`, you can then query the `/db/test` collection using the `ft:query` function and sort the results using the `ft:score` function:

```
let $hits := 
    ( 
        collection('/db/test/articles')/article/body,
        collection('/db/test/people')/people/person/biography
    )[ft:query(., $q)]
for $hit in $hits
let $score := ft:score($hit)
order by $score descending
return $hit
```

(Notice that in contrast to the article, we can dispense with filtering the user-supplied query string, because we are no longer using `util:eval`. That wasn't really necessary in the first place.)

With this change - switching to eXist's newer Lucene-based full text search engine - the rest of the article should still basically apply.